# Google Cloud - Yii2 The directory is not writable by the Web process | frontend/web/assets

Tags: php, yii2, google-cloud-platform

I've uploaded the Yii2 advanced site on google cloud server.

I've created instance with Centos 7

Getting error :
**The directory is not writable by the Web process | frontend/web/assets**

I've also set the **permission 777** but still not working

how can I resolve the error.

Comment: have you verified after changing the permission that it is change or not?
You can check it by using this command
`ls -la`

Comment: yes I've checked it show the permission "drwxrwxr-x." is changed but not understanding what happen

Comment: all folders have same permission? or only the root?

Comment: try this 
`sudo chmod -R 777 frontend/web/assets`

Comment: finally resolve the issue. thanks for your help.

Comment: main problem with selinux setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step to follow to resolve the issue - [Reference link](https://discuss.flarum.org/d/4126-directory-is-not-writable-tried-different-solution)

1. Login with SSH from your google cloud instance.
2. In SSH login as root user

   [yourgmailname@instance-name ~]$ su // enter su for login as root

   Password: // enter your password
3. Go to var dirctory

   [root@instance-name var]# getenforce

   Enforcing // output
4. If you see the **Enforcing**
5. Go to selinux

   [root@instance-name var]# vi /etc/selinux/config

   - You will see the below code

## This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.

```
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=enforcing
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected.
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

6. Change the **SELINUX=enforcing** to **SELINUX=disabled** and save the file
7. Reboot the server

   [root@instance-name var]# reboot

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if disabling SELINUX is the answer as I've read too many warnings about that.

Found the following solution somewhere (my apologies to the original poster).
Just execute the following once you SSH into your instance:

```
sudo chcon -v --type=httpd_sys_script_rw_t frontend/web/assets
```

Comment: Good point that disabling SELinux is not a good idea. It would be nice if you add some more details to your answer and explain what this command actually does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: Sorry Nima. I'm not a CentOS expert. It's just that that particular solution worked for me as per the question raised.