# Linux and Yii - The directory is not writable by the Web process: /web/assets

Tags: linux, yii2, vagrant, selinux

I installed Yii2 on Ubuntu 16.04 using Vagrant and when I try to load some page, Yii gives me an error:

```
The directory is not writable by the Web process: /web/assets
```

I found some solutions but they don't work because of SELinux. I tried to disable it using `setenforce 0` but command line prints:

```
setenforce: command not found.
```

I noticed that almost no one has this error and I don't know what did I do wrong or what should I do. Please help!

Comment: Try this `sudo chown -R [USER NAME]:www-data /var/www`

Comment: doesn't work, I've asked in another site and one man said that I can't change permissions because I have different usernames on host and virtual machines, I checked `config.yaml` file and found 2 lines: `synced_folders -> owner` and `ssh -> username` and both equal "vagrant", maybe I should rename it to "www-data" and what line?

Comment: Might be same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42711277/57091)

Answer (score 0):

`chmod 777 /path/to/web/assets`

This allows **any** user to read/write/execute. On servers, this is usually not recommended, but in some cases its hard to avoid. We had to do this for the runtime, the assets and the uploads folder with Vagrant. It might be worth noting that we only used Vagrant in the development environment but not in production.